# what is the running time for this algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

what is the running time

```
   String[] stringCombo = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringCombo.length; i++) {
        stringCombo[i] = deleteCharAt(s,i);
        s = original;
    }
```

i am not sure if it is O(N), because the length is fixed to be 5.

```
private static String deleteFirstChar(String s) {
    return s.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: it depends on the running time as deleteCharAt()

Comment: In these questions, `N` has to mean something. What is it here? The total number of characters in the 5 strings?

Comment: private static String deleteFirstChar(String s) {
        return s.substring(1);
    }

Comment: Running time is 20 minutes. I just checked

Comment: @Doejo I think you're confusing `deleteCharAt()` with `deleteFirstChar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java source for [[String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cchar[]%29)]. Look at `substring` and you will find that the order of `substring(..)` is O(1) (before Java 6). *[[For Java >= 7, substring actually involves copying of the (sub)array which is an `O(N)` operation (see Paul Boddington's comment below)]]*

You are doing this 5 times, which is **fixed**. So, regardless of `N`(?), this code will run 5 times.

**Q:** Do you think this depends on `N`?

**A:** No.

Order is O(1).

Comment: You're looking at an old version of `substring`. It used to be `O(1)`, but now it's linear in the number of characters because it copies the array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123446/java-7-string-substring-complexity

Comment: Oh yes! Copying of arrays is an `O(N)` operation for Java >= 7. I keep making this mistake! Thanks, @PaulBoddington. I'll edit it.